Como puedo exportar e importar mi pryecto de Android Studio con Git?
Intento importar el proyecto desde git a otra pc pero me aparece este error, que puedo hacer?...

Tengo el proyecto en mi PC que funciona bien, pero quiero poder seguir trabajando en él desde mi laptop cuando no esté en la PC. El problema es que, al intentar importar el proyecto desde Git en la laptop, me aparece un error. Creo que tal vez no estoy subiéndolo correctamente, y me gustaría saber cómo hacerlo bien para poder trabajar sin problemas desde las dos computadoras.


Hola.. que tiene que ver git con este problema?? ahi parece que te faltan librerias.. las instalaste?

Ya tienes vinculado todo lo que es el repositorio con tu Android Studio?, o lo estas haciendo todo directo mediante bash?
Intenta con: Build > Clean project > Rebuild project, puede ayudarte a corregir algún error que tengas entre medias

Bienvenido. ¿Qué librerías estás usando? ¿El proyecto es tuyo? ¿En algún momento compiló correctamente? Yo creo que el problema no es de git, sino que debes haber olvidado algunos archivos importantes. Pon el error como texto, muestra el archivo build.gradle.kts, el .gitignore también como texto y los primeros 2 niveles de archivos en tu proyecto por las dudas. También podes dejar el link del repo

por favor agrega mas contexto, como el contendo el archivo build.gradle.kts para tratar de entender tu problema y asi podamos ayudarte

Agrega el contenido de tu archivo .gitignore y muestra que tienes dentro del directorio /libs por favor @Yesler
